# Как преобразовать xslt в html для указанного документа

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть большой `xml` c описанием печатных изданий, его необходимо при помощи `xslt` преобразовать его в `html`. Я не очень хорошо знаю `xslt`, но почти сделал это преобразование... Остался лишь небольшой кусок документа с которым я никак не могу справится.

Думаю что нужно использовать оси, но понятия не имею какие ))

Кусок xml с которым у меня затруднения (специально уменьшен):

## xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<folder>
<document>
        <h1>Harry Potter</h1>
        <h2>j.rowling</h2>
        <subheading>book</subheading>
    </document>
    <document>
        <p type="num">
            <num>55</num>           
        </p>
        <h1>Hi-Tech</h1>
    </document>
</folder>
```

Затруднения возникли с этим:

- если найден порядок элементов **h1, h2, subheading**, то отобразить **h1** и **subheading** на одной строке, после чего вывести элемент **h2**;
- если перед элементом **h1** находится элемент "**p**" с атрибутом **type="num"**, внутри которого есть не пустой элемент **num** -  отобразить его на одной строке с элементом **h1**.

Направьте в нужном направлении. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать отдельные шаблоны для каждого случая. Что-то вроде:

```
<xsl:template match="document[h1 and h2 and subheading]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(h1,' ',subheading)"/>
  <br/>
  <xsl:value-of select="h2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="document[p[@type='num'][num] and h1]">  
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(h1,' ',p)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: спасибо! то что нужно! я пытался сделать что-то подобное, но из-за нехватки опыта не получалось ))